# Splitting repeating text without delimiter?

Tags: java, regex

Given a string, I want to split up all instance of the substring "foo".

If I have a text like "foofoofoobarbar", I want to split it by wherever foo appears into the String array { "foo" , "foo", "foo", "barbar"}

I don't understand how to use regex when there's not an obvious delimiter to look for

```
String text= "foofoofoobarbar"
String[] splitted = text.split( ??????? );
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: How should "foobarfoo" be split?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use lookarounds.

```
String[] splitted = text.split("((?<=foo)(?=.)|(?<=.)(?=foo))")
```

Comment: @user432 Yes.  See latest fix.  `"(?=foo)"` fails for "foobarfoo"

Comment: @user432 Don't delete comment that are correct but outdated, they are required for context of later comments.

Answer (score 3):

Make it easy:

```
String text= "foofoofoobarbar"
text.replace("foo","foo ");
String[] splitted = text.split(" ");
```